# How to add virtual NICs to my linux PC, so that they expose their MACs to ISP's domain?

Tags: linux, networking, virtualization, iptables, vlan

I have learned how to add virtual NICs to a guest system in VirtualBox, just using `Shared Adapter`, then all the virtual NICs and my host's NIC will appear as real NICs to the ISP.

So I guess there must be a way to add those virtual NICs to my PC without resolving VBox. I tried with `ip link add link enp0s3 type macvlan`.

```
ip netns add ns
ip link add link enp0s3 type macvlan
ip link set netns ns macvlan0
ip netns exec ns ip link set up macvlan0
ip netns exec ns ip addr add 192.168.222.101/24 dev macvlan0
ip addr add 192.168.222.1/24 dev enp0s3
ping 192.168.222.101
PING 192.168.222.101 (192.168.222.101) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.222.101 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1999ms
```

I also tried `ip link add link enp0s3 type macvlan mode bridge` and `ip link add link enp0s3 type macvtap [mode bridge]`, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably to use `macvlans`. Similar solutions are [macvtap](http://virt.kernelnewbies.org/MacVTap) and [ipvlan](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ipvlan.txt), which differ only minimally from the above; it is difficult to choose one rather than the other, without many more details. But the following will surely work.

For every network namespace, assign a macvlan interface as follows:

```
 NNS=TheNameOfYourNetworkNamespace
 ip netns add $NNS
 ip link add link eth0 mac$NNS address 56:61:4f:7c:77:db type macvlan mode bridge
 ip link set dev mac$NNS netns $NNS
```

I have used a specific MAC address, you may simply drop the part `address 56:61:4f:7c:77:db` if you are not interested in specifying it, thus leaving it to chance.

Now enter the network namespace and configure the network:

```
 ip netns exec $NNS xterm
```

and from within the open `xterm`, do:

```
 ip link set dev $NAME_OF_MAC_INTERFACE up
 ip link set dev lo up
 ip addr add 127.0.0.1 dev lo
 dhclient -v mac$NNS
```

and you are done.

One last comment: the option `mode bridge` used above allows all network namespaces to talk to each other directly, *i.e.* without passing thru a switch. However, whether you use such an option or not, your **host** will be unable to talk to the network namespaces, *unless* you build a macvlan for the host itself, in which case it will be able to communicate with the other NNSes as if it itself were one of them.

**EDIT:**

it does not work because I should have remembered that, once inside the NNS, environment variables like $NNS are not defined any longer, so that I should correct the line above. In fact, on my system,

```
 # ip addr show dev eth0
   2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e8:e0:b7:be:72:6a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
   inet 192.168.73.55/24 brd 192.168.73.255 scope global eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   inet6 fe80::eae0:b7ff:febe:726a/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  # NNS=ns1
  # ip netns add $NNS
  # ip link add link eth0 mac$NNS address 56:61:4f:7c:77:db type macvlan 
  # ip link set dev mac$NNS netns $NNS
  # ip netns exec $NNS /bin/bash
  # ip link set dev macns1 up
  #  ip link set dev lo up
  #  ip addr add 127.0.0.1 dev lo
  # dhclient -v macns1
    Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4
    Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
    All rights reserved.
    For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

    Listening on LPF/macns1/56:61:4f:7c:77:db
    Sending on   LPF/macns1/56:61:4f:7c:77:db
    Sending on   Socket/fallback
    DHCPDISCOVER on macns1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x473d2846)
    DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.73.48 on macns1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x46283d47)
    DHCPOFFER of 192.168.73.48 from 192.168.73.1
    DHCPACK of 192.168.73.48 from 192.168.73.1
    bound to 192.168.73.48 -- renewal in 21288 seconds.
  # ping -c1 superuser.com
    PING superuser.com (104.16.127.192) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from 104.16.127.192: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=12.9 ms

    --- superuser.com ping statistics ---
    1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
    rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 12.927/12.927/12.927/0.000 ms
```

As you can see, it works perfectly on my system. You can check that the IP address I get within the NNS (192.168.73.48) differs from that on the host, 192.168.73.55.

If it does not work on your system, I will need something more than just a *it does not work*, because I am unable to reproduce your error.

Comment: I tried your answer, but I'm sorry to tell you it doesn't work. In fact, I tried `arp -s` in `$NNS` and it gives `192.168.42.129 (incomplete)`. The IP is my gateway. I tried in the default namespace it gives the right MAC.

Comment: @TorosFanny Pls read my Edit.

Comment: It's really strange. I have forgotten to tell you, I do nearly all of my experiments in VirtualBox. Once I gave the guest Ubuntu a `bridged adapter`, and then `dhclient -v mac$NNS` failed, and I tried to give the guest a `NAT`, and then `dhclient -v mac$NNS` success. With the `NAT` mode, I can also `ping -c1 superuser.com`, but can not still ping the NIC of guest os's default namespace. It's really strange, it can ping the outside world but not the NIC linked to it. I tried your answer with my real PC, it works fine. Maybe there's something wrong with `shared adapter` mode. Thank you.